# Angular - Can't make ng-repeat orderBy work

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've tried many examples of ng-repeat with orderBy, but I can't make my json work with it.

```
<div ng-app>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.1/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
    <div ng:controller="Main">
        <div ng-repeat="release in releases| orderBy:'environment_id'">      
            {{release.environment_id}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JSON

```
function Main($scope) {
$scope.releases = {
    "tvl-c-wbap001 + tvl-webapp": {
        "timestamp": " 05:05:53 PM ",
        "environment_id": "CERT5",
        "release_header": "Projects/Dev",
        "date": "19 Oct",
        "release": "12.11.91-1"
    },
    "tvl-c-wbap401 + tvl-webapp": {
        "timestamp": " 10:07:25 AM ",
        "environment_id": "CERT4",
        "release_header": "Future Release",
        "date": "15 Oct",
        "release": "485-1"
    },
    "tvl-c-wbap301 + tvl-webapp": {
        "timestamp": " 07:59:48 AM ",
        "environment_id": "CERT3",
        "release_header": "Next Release",
        "date": "15 Oct",
        "release": "485-1"
    },
    "tvl-c-wbap201 + tvl-webapp": {
        "timestamp": " 03:34:07 AM ",
        "environment_id": "CERT2",
        "release_header": "Next Changes",
        "date": "15 Oct",
        "release": "13.12.3-1"
    },
    "tvl-c-wbap101 + tvl-webapp": {
        "timestamp": " 12:44:23 AM ",
        "environment_id": "CERT1",
        "release_header": "Production Mirror",
        "date": "15 Oct",
        "release": "13.11.309-1"
    },
    "tvl-s-wbap002 + tvl-webapp": {
        "timestamp": " 12:43:23 AM ",
        "environment_id": "Stage2",
        "date": "15 Oct",
        "release": "13.11.310-1"
    },
    "tvl-s-wbap001 + tvl-webapp": {
        "timestamp": " 11:07:38 AM ",
        "environment_id": "Stage1",
        "release_header": "Production Mirror",
        "date": "11 Oct",
        "release": "13.11.310-1"
    },
    "tvl-p-wbap001 + tvl-webapp": {
        "timestamp": " 11:39:25 PM ",
        "environment_id": "Production",
        "release_header": "Pilots",
        "date": "14 Oct",
        "release": "13.11.310-1"
    },
    "tvl-p-wbap100 + tvl-webapp": {
        "timestamp": " 03:27:53 AM ",
        "environment_id": "Production",
        "release_header": "Non Pilots",
        "date": "11 Oct",
        "release": "13.11.309-1"
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter what I write, I always get the same order, or I may say, no order at all.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The `orderBy` only works with Arrays -- See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy

Also a great filter to use for Objects instead of Arrays @ [Angularjs OrderBy on ng-repeat doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920028/angularjs-orderby-on-ng-repeat-doesnt-work)

Comment: I have an array, but this does not work in Chrome. Do you know why?

Answer (score 90):

As mentioned, only arrays are allowed. But to make it simple for you, you could dynamically convert the object into an array via a piping function as seen here
https://gist.github.com/brev/3949705

Just declare the filter, and add it to ng-repeat :)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="Main">
  <div ng-repeat="release in releases | object2Array | orderBy:'environment_id'">{{release.environment_id}}</div>
</div>

<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []).filter('object2Array', function() {
    return function(input) {
      var out = []; 
      for(i in input){
        out.push(input[i]);
      }
      return out;
    }
  })
.controller('Main',function ($scope) {
        $scope.releases = {"tvl-c-wbap001 + tvl-webapp":{"timestamp":" 05:05:53 PM ","environment_id":"CERT5","release_header":"Projects/Dev","date":"19 Oct","release":"12.11.91-1"},"tvl-c-wbap401 + tvl-webapp":{"timestamp":" 10:07:25 AM ","environment_id":"CERT4","release_header":"Future Release","date":"15 Oct","release":"485-1"},"tvl-c-wbap301 + tvl-webapp":{"timestamp":" 07:59:48 AM ","environment_id":"CERT3","release_header":"Next Release","date":"15 Oct","release":"485-1"},"tvl-c-wbap201 + tvl-webapp":{"timestamp":" 03:34:07 AM ","environment_id":"CERT2","release_header":"Next Changes","date":"15 Oct","release":"13.12.3-1"},"tvl-c-wbap101 + tvl-webapp":{"timestamp":" 12:44:23 AM ","environment_id":"CERT1","release_header":"Production Mirror","date":"15 Oct","release":"13.11.309-1"},"tvl-s-wbap002 + tvl-webapp":{"timestamp":" 12:43:23 AM ","environment_id":"Stage2","date":"15 Oct","release":"13.11.310-1"},"tvl-s-wbap001 + tvl-webapp":{"timestamp":" 11:07:38 AM ","environment_id":"Stage1","release_header":"Production Mirror","date":"11 Oct","release":"13.11.310-1"},"tvl-p-wbap001 + tvl-webapp":{"timestamp":" 11:39:25 PM ","environment_id":"Production","release_header":"Pilots","date":"14 Oct","release":"13.11.310-1"},"tvl-p-wbap100 + tvl-webapp":{"timestamp":" 03:27:53 AM ","environment_id":"Production","release_header":"Non Pilots","date":"11 Oct","release":"13.11.309-1"}}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I use simpler `toArray` filter: `function(obj){return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){return obj[key];});}`

Comment: Awesome...just awesome. Thanks for posting this. Big help!

Comment: Im not sure if this happens with filters, but if you create an array on each sort using a function, the $digest triggers more than once. Can anyone tell if this happens using filter too? See https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

Comment: Could it be that not only arrays are supported for orderBy now? De doc link states: "Array-like values (e.g. NodeLists, jQuery objects, TypedArrays, Strings, etc) are also supported."

Answer (score 29):

the built-in orderBy filter will no longer work when iterating an object. It’s ignored due to the way that object fields are stored. You need create a custom filter

```
yourApp.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderObjectBy:'color':true">{{ item.color }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 11):

in Eike Thies's response above, if we use underscore.js, filter could be simplified to :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).filter('object2Array', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return _.toArray(input);
  }
});
```

Comment: Best answer so far! Awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version of @Julian Mosquera's code that also supports sorting by object **key**:

```
yourApp.filter('orderObjectBy', function () {
    return function (items, field, reverse) {
        // Build array
        var filtered = [];
        for (var key in items) {
            if (field === 'key')
                filtered.push(key);
            else
                filtered.push(items[key]);
        }
        // Sort array
        filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (field === 'key')
                return (a > b ? 1 : -1);
            else
                return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
        });
        // Reverse array
        if (reverse)
            filtered.reverse();
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to reformat your releases object to be an **array** of objects. Then you'll be able to sort them the way you're attempting.

Answer (score 1):

orderby works on arrays that contain objects with immidiate values which can be used as filters, ie

```
controller.images = [{favs:1,name:"something"},{favs:0,name:"something else"}];
```

When the above array is repeated, you may use | orderBy:'favs' to refer to that value immidiately, or use a minus in front to order descending

```
<div class="timeline-image" ng-repeat="image in controller.images | orderBy:'-favs'">
    <img ng-src="{{ images.name }}"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of @Julian Mosquera's code that also supports a "fallback" field to use in case the primary field happens to be null or undefined:

```
yourApp.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, fallback, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      var af = a[field];
      if(af === undefined || af === null) { af = a[fallback]; }

      var bf = b[field];
      if(bf === undefined || bf === null) { bf = b[fallback]; }

      return (af > bf ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});
```