# Unable to get scope object in function after 1.3

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code:

```
            $scope.getObject = function(object) {
                var rootobject = $scope[object];
                console.log(rootobject);
                return rootobject;
            };
```

It is a getter for a $scope variable.

Then I have this $scope variable setter:

```
            $scope.setObject = function(object,value){
                console.log("saving " + value + " to " + object);
                $scope[object] = value;
            };
```

Good so far?

Now before 1.30 I was using it in an ng-repeat for **orderBy**

```
<div ng-repeat="content in sitedata.content | toArray | orderBy:getObject(block.tags) ng-include src="'block.html'"  ></div>
```

However, since 1.30 and later it no longer works.

The console logs the items appropriately but the orderBy never changes.

I can't see anything in the patch logs to point to this... any ideas?

Comment: Can you show an example of `content` and `block.tags`?

Comment: In ```<div ng-repeat="content in sitedata.content | toArray | orderBy:getObject(block.tags)```, your ng-repeat does not seem to have a closing quotation mark (```"```), can you check? Is this unrelated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920028/angularjs-orderby-on-ng-repeat-doesnt-work

Comment: Can you provide a Plnkr with this in running?

Answer (score 0):

You should move to a prototypal pattern and leverage this & .bind() to avoid these issues.  I do similar stuff in Angular and have found it a LOT more convenient.  Best I can offer!

Here is an example of a [prototypal controller](https://github.com/cubicleDowns/ng-three-viewer/blob/master/v2/src/js/ng/app-controller.js).