# AngularJS: filtering and ordering using orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm learning AngularJS and I need some help please. In this app the idea is to have an input field that enables the user to type in their ordering criteria: author, date and rating. These could be prefixed with a '-' sign to indicate reverse ordering. The ideal is to be able to use only one input field to access different kind of criteria just writing the key word: author, date, etc. 
I'm having problems to use the filters using orderBy.

Thanks a lot!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="confusionApp" lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
     content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as MenuController">

        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation">
                  <h3>{{MenuController.dish.category}}</h3>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="media-body">
                <div class="media-left">
                    <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{MenuController.dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                </div> 
                <div class="media-body">   
                    <h2 class="media-heading">{{MenuController.dish.name}}
                    <span class="label label-danger">{{MenuController.dish.label}}</span>
                    <span class="badge">{{MenuController.dish.price | currency}}</span>
                    <p>{{MenuController.dish.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
                  <p><strong>Customer Comments</strong>    Sort by <input type="text" data-ng-model="searchCustom"  ></p>
                  <div ng-repeat=" commentControll in MenuController.dish.comments | filter:searchCustom | orderBy: 'HERE THE PROBLEM' ">
                      <blockquote>
                          <p>Stars: {{commentControll.rating}}</p>
                          <p>{{commentControll.comment}}</p>
                          <footer>{{commentControll.author}}, {{ commentControll.date | date:'medium'}}</footer>
                      </blockquote>
                  </div> 
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);

    app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

        var dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains', 
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }

                       ]
                };

        this.dish = dish;

    });

</script>




</body></html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920028/angularjs-orderby-on-ng-repeat-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. You can use input field for filtering but it's not a good idea to order data by what user enters.

orderBy takes object key as the input with second Boolean field to reverse the order. User may not know the key of the Object. So better provide a drop down or something like that to provide all the available orderBy options and then internally pass the object key to the orderBy. May be youcan keep an check box for reversing the order.

For more information on orderBy check the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) or check this [blog post](http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/).

Comment: order data by what user enters it's part of the exercise, beyond right or wrong I have to do it in that way

Comment: Then directly pass the value to orderBy. It'll work only when the data entered by user matches the object keys. May be you can show the available options as placeholder to make things easier. Try to use a separate input for OrderBy.