# Passing json value to OrderBy in html template

Tags: angularjs

I'm iterating over an object and trying to OrderBy the Heading's based on the ColPos value. But this does not work and orderby is not set how can I resolve this ?

```
<th ng-repeat="(key, value) in instancesData.Attributes | orderBy:'value.ColPos'" >
     <span>{{key}}</span>
</th>
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/X90n24vx2wqKvXZuDYLJ?p=preview

Comment: You are trying to use the filter orderBy with an object, but this filter only works with Arrays, you will have to either change the model to an Array or make your own filter.

Comment: See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy

Comment: understood will write a custom filter

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387552/angular-cant-make-ng-repeat-orderby-work

Comment: @gearsdigital the most voted version of that question won't solve the OP's problem because the keys of the object are not being stored in the resulting array of the 'object2Array' custom filter.

Comment: @user1184100 writing that custom filter it's not going to be easy, since you will have to preserve the keys of the objects, it's quite likely that you will run into an infinite diggest loop issue... Because that filter will have to create new elements every time you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already said in the comments: you are trying to use the filter `orderBy` with an `object`, but this filter only works with `Arrays`, you will have to either change the model to an `Array` or make your own `filter`.

I will give you a solution for the first option.

In your controller do this:

```
$scope.dataAttributesArray = 
   Object.keys($scope.instancesData.Attributes).map(function(key){
      return {key:key, val:$scope.instancesData.Attributes[key]};
   });
```

And then in your view you can do this:

```
<th ng-repeat="attribute in dataAttributesArray | orderBy:'val.ColPos'" data-x="{{value.ColPos}}" >
        <span>{{attribute.key}}</span>
</th>
```

### [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2mbf8tScbxLpoGvPQ0sU?p=preview)