# AngularJS: Sorting Strings With Spaces Using orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have an ng-repeat going, wherein:

```
<a ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy:'name'">
{{contact.name}}
</a>
```

I have tried predicates: name, -name, name.substr(0, 3)

The contacts 'name' property is like "John Smith", "Betty Ford", "Hawkeye Pierce", etc.

The ng-repeat works, but the orderBy does not.

Is there a reason that my strings might not be sorting successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 : The orderBy only works with Arrays -- See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy

source : [Angular - Can't make ng-repeat orderBy work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387552/angular-cant-make-ng-repeat-orderby-work)

What is your 'contacts' ?

2 : try

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy:'name'">
<a>{{contact.name}}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working link for your case

Hope it helps for you

```
'http://plnkr.co/edit/EhV5RHszZns5qTHM8qBu?p=preview'
```