# How to get previous object in ng-repeat after orderBy is applied

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have an array of objects that have a "Category" property. In my ng-repeat, I am creating a group by conditionally showing a header row with the category name if it is different that the previous value by using `items[$index - 1]` to check the previous value. This works, but if I apply an orderBy filter, it would seem that $index doesn't reflect the new order. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as I posted this, I realized what might fix it. I added `track by item.itemId` and it started acting as expected.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items track by item.itemId | filter: searchTerms | orderBy:['Category1', 'Category2']">
  <div class="rowHeader" ng-show="$index == 0 || item.Category1 != items[$index -1].Category1">
    {{item.Category1}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working for me, I always get a random previous object. Also, when I put the "track by" statement before the orderBy pipe, my list is not ordered. When I put "track by" after the orderBy, the list is ordered.

Comment: As seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15413253/4519548), you have to be aware of orderBy messing up the elements and create a correct array instead.