# How to compare values inside ng-repeat.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to compare values inside `ng-repeat`. How to compare previous value with current value inside `ng-repeat`. I have an array, having values [2,3]. I want to compare array second value with first. How to do it?
**Update**: I am displaying current month and date and next seven days. Now if in next seven days there is new month, i mean as january after december, I need to include this month just before the dates of this month.
**Ex::** Dec Tue 30, Wed 31, Jan Thu 1, Fri 2 ....

All code is here: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9763/

```
 <div class="row" style="text-align:center;background-color: #930d14; color: white; height: 55px;">
            <div class="col" style="border-right: solid 1px #820d13;">
                <p style="transform: rotate(270deg);margin-top: 8px;font-size: 10px;font-weight: 600;text-transform: uppercase;">
                    {{currentMonth}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col" style="border-right: solid 1px #820d13;" ng-repeat="days in totalDays.aryDates">
                <p style="font-size: 10px;font-weight: 500;">{{days}}</p>
                <p ng-if="totalDays.aryDates[$index-1] !== totalDays.aryDates[$index]" style="transform: rotate(270deg);margin-top: 8px;font-size: 10px;font-weight: 600;text-transform: uppercase;">
                    {{newMonth}}</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: show your relevant code...

Comment: can u provide your scenario. what is your exact requirement

Comment: Actually my requirement is little complex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412897/how-to-obtain-previous-item-in-ng-repeat this is possible solution

Comment: I am updating the question.

Comment: Your update does not clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

Angular.js loops have $index. You can use

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
     <span ng-show="items[$index-1] == items[$index]"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you want to do ? what's your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

In the ng-repeat you can refer to $index inside the loop. So access the array elements as array[$index] array [$index+1]

Comment: It is working but my requirement is not fulfilled. I am updating my question.

Comment: Your question asked about comparing values in an ng-repeat. This answers that question. If you have another question then post another question. SO is for answering questions, not fulfilling 'your requirements'