# How to access previous key/value pair in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My AngularJs app reads a json file having key/value pairs. The key/value pairs are generated by a java program using HashMap.

I am trying to generate HTML using ng-repeat directive in AngularJs in the following manner.

```
<li ng-repeat="(line, lineContents) in errorsFromLogFile">
    {{line}} - {{lineContents}} 
</li>
```

I also want to access the previous (key / value) pair.

Gone through these stackoverflow links [How to obtain previous item in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412897/how-to-obtain-previous-item-in-ng-repeat), [Compare values inside ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776855/how-to-compare-values-inside-ng-repeat) and tried to access the previous key as

```
{{ errorsFromLogFile[$index-1].line }}
```

but it gives nothing. How to access previous key/value in this case?

The json file looks like this

```
- errorsFromLogFile: {
     7308: "/tmp/cct7oRJm.s:2099392: Warning: .stabs: description field '11668' too big, try a different debug format",
     7309: "/tmp/cct7oRJm.s:2099393: Warning: .stabs: description field '120d3' too big, try a different debug format",
     7310: "/tmp/cct7oRJm.s:2099394: Warning: .stabs: description field '128a6' too big, try a different debug format",
     7311: "/tmp/cct7oRJm.s:2099395: Warning: .stabs: description field '13046' too big, try a different debug format",
     7312: "/tmp/cct7oRJm.s:2099396: Warning: .stabs: description field '1386c' too big, try a different debug format",
   }
```

Comment: Can you show your JSON file?

Comment: if you are not using any filter on ng-repeat then you could easily get the track of past record using `errorsFromLogFile[$index-1] == errorsFromLogFile[$index]`

Comment: Here http://plnkr.co/edit/G1CSS7g99TrrmemhH9Tt?p=preview everything works fine.

Comment: @kraja:Check the below answer?

Comment: @PankajParkar This works for arrays not objects. The json returned is an object map.

Comment: @DianaR errorsFromLogFile is an array of objects so it works. But will not work for object map.

Comment: Oh. than this changes the solution. Here is a working one:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wGIBxWNIm6Z0MoDH1Xys?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use internal property `$$prevSibling` which gives the previous sibling scope and in this case previous scope created by `ng-repeat`. This is because you are using an object map and not Array. `errorsFromLogFile[$index-1]` will not work in array of objects because it just means that you are trying to access value of property index from the array, i.e `errorsFromLogFile[0], errorsFromLogFile[1]` etc.

i.e **`{{$$prevSibling.line}}`** and **`{{$$prevSibling.lineContents}}`** which should work, but is not advisable to use private properties on scope.

Another better suggestion is to convert it to array of objects and just have regular `ng-repeat` iteration syntax and get the previous item using the index.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the issue. Since I am using object map not Array, and accessing keys in a serial fashion is not possible [Access first property of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/access-the-first-property-of-an-object). Now I get all the keys _(lines)_ from the object _(errorsFromLogFile)_ and use **ng-repeat** over it.