# Updating values inside an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use AngularJS's ng-repeat to check if a value from a previous iteration is the same as the current.

```
if previous === current
```

After, the check I would like to update previous to equal current.

```
previous = current
```

I have no idea how to update values from inside an ng-repeat in Angular.

Here is an example:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in Products  | filter: filters[0] | orderBy:'Section'">

      <div ng-if="product.Section !== $parent.previous">
           {{product.Section}}
      </div>

      $parent.previous = product.Section
</div>
```

**Update:**

While this question might still be helpful in some situations, after some thought I realised that what I really want is new objects grouping products by section: [How can I group data with an Angular filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter)

Comment: I think we're going to need to see a more complete example of your code to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412897/how-to-obtain-previous-item-in-ng-repeat

Comment: That's a good solution, but I have found that `$index` does not represent the previous item once sorting has been applied. I have tried using `track by $index` and other values, but that has caused me nothing but trouble so far.

Comment: Interesting. The thing that is occurring to me might work, but is so hackish I refuse to offer it as a real answer. There has to be something better. However, `<div ng-if="product.Section !== $parent.previous && ($parent.previous = product.Section)">` will probably work.

Comment: That does work. Thank you. It might be hacky, but I'm desperate enough to roll with it for now.

Comment: As a 'bonus', short-circuit evaluation means it'll only update your previous when you find a new section...