# How can we use ng-repeat first row values to populate the values in next rows?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to populate a *checkbox*, a *label* and two *text boxes* on ng-repeat loop.

When the *checkbox* is selected, its corresponding row is enabled for *text boxes* to be editable. I need to get the data entered in the first row and then copy that data to the next rows which ever is selected.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="option in coverages"> 
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="{{option}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="optionChecked" class="border-horizontal" />
    <label for="{{option}}">{{option}}</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm border-horizontal" ng-disabled="!optionChecked" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm border-horizontal" ng-disabled="!optionChecked" /> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post code you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks, but that code should be added to the original post, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to know if previous value is checked and you neeed to access previous value, then you can probably refer to this
[How to obtain previous item in ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412897/how-to-obtain-previous-item-in-ng-repeat)
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: The previous field might not be selected.....i can make use of only the first row text field and populate that textbox column of the grid with that value.

Comment: if you just want the first value you can directly access it coverages[0] should give you the first row value